# shapely fast union difference

Tags: python, shapely

I am using shapely for union and difference operations on some geometry. To improve performance I want to use a Rtree.

Do you guys have any suggestions for an efficient data structure? It should also handle nested geometries, e.g. a donut shape that has inside a circle.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I want restrict the geometry and all geometries for the binary operations to be of topological dimension 2.

Comment: As far as I recall rtree can help for point in bounding box type queries, but can't immediately think of manner to use it for speeding up more advanced geometry operations. BTW, redis geo commands (v3.2) now supports basic spatial queries, and is similar to rtree except that it uses radii instead of bbox.

Comment: Or does this thing have a name? I was thinking also, that this can be implemented by defining a sequence of rings adding an orientation for telling if the interior includes the binary segmentation given by the geometry. The binary operations would then use ring intersections to modify existing rings and add new ones.